# Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: c#

> Object doesn't support this property or method
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: (sheepinshly)...sorry, I've seen this one, but I honestly don't mind seeing it again.

Comment: -1 for not being able to read the content of an exception, another -1 for asking no question, another -1 for providing no code - I wish I could vote that often...

Answer (score 3):

Quite possibly one of the most straightforward, honest and accurate exception messages of all time. My second favorite, after "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

You are calling `SomeObject.SomeMethod()` and that version of the object does not support that method. So it throws the exception to let you know. Fix it by not calling that method.